# Is there any way to get a sqrt of a matrix in NumPy? Not element wise, but as a whole

Tags: numpy

For example, for matrix A, we have

`A.dot(A) = B`

Now I have B, want to get A. I tried `np.sqrt(B)`, but this can only get the sqrt of every number is B, not A. I searched the internet, but found nothing.

Is there any way to get A in NumPy?

For example

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.random.randint(low=1, high=5, size=(4,4))
ar2 = ar.dot(ar)
ar1 = np.sqrt(ar2)
```

Then we will find that ar1 is not the same as ar. If we now know ar2, how can we get ar?

Comment: Sum it first? `np.sqrt(B.sum())` ?

Comment: A and B are matrix. This code will get a number only.

Comment: Could you show some sample input and output please?

Comment: You can only get `ar` if you have what `ar` was dotted with... since you're dotting it with itself and that's what you're trying to find... then...

Comment: ar2 = ar * ar  then ar1 = np.sqrt(ar2) would work, as it is an element-wise matrix multiplication. I would suggest you look into the difference between a*b and a.dot(b) in NumPy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can do it [using scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.sqrtm.html#scipy.linalg.sqrtm).

If you want to do it with numpy however, then I think that your best guess is to diagonalize your matrix and then to compute the square root of the inner diagonal matrix.

```py
# Computing diagonalization
evalues, evectors = np.linalg.eig(a)
# Ensuring square root matrix exists
assert (evalues >= 0).all()
sqrt_matrix = evectors * np.sqrt(evalues) @ np.linalg.inv(evectors)
```

Note that you can speed up computation if your matrix is symmetric real (use `np.eigh` and you don't have to compute the inverse since it is the transpose of `evectors`).

Comment: Will scipy be faster than this implementation if the matrix is symmetric real?